# Multithreading Merge sort algorithm

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

I have been trying to understand the code for multithreaded merge sort algorithm.

I understood everything, but I can not run the threads. Here is the source of the code:

https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/13wi/lectures/03-13/MergeSort.java

The problem is occuring here:

```
Thread lThread = new Thread(new Sorter(left,  threadCount / 2));

Thread rThread = new Thread(new Sorter(right, threadCount / 2));
```

It says that

> Sorter can not be resolved to a type

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: If you use dependencies outside the package they should be referenced in the same package to let the compiler know how to resolve these dependencies.

Comment: Well is there a `Sorter` class?

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Inside the "root" link of he lecture that you mention in your question...

https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/13wi/lectures/03-13/

[image]

And I can see clearly the file called `Sorter.java` so it seems that you need to keep reading and understanding the given example/lecture